# Recording Audio from Yamaha P45 on a MacBook

Tags: piano, recording, audio, equipment, cable

I have a Yamaha P45 whose audio I want to record — I use headphones when I practice so I know there is an audio output that's not MIDI. Does anyone know what kind of cables / equipment / software I can use to directly record the audio output of the Yamaha P45 to my laptop live as I am playing? I have looked in the user manual and browsed around online without much success

Comment: did you try search on youtube like this https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=Yamaha+P45+record+sound+on+computer&page&utm_source=opensearch ?

Comment: Yes, I actually found a some pretty good videos after posting this question, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you're just looking to make a quick and dirty recording, without any particular processing. In that case, you just need a cable to go from the keyboard audio out (the headphones plug) to the MacBook's audio in (the microphone plug). From there, you can use any on-board sound recording software, like QuickTime ([instructions](https://support.apple.com/guide/quicktime-player/record-audio-qtpf25d6f827/mac)) or Voice Memos ([instructions](https://support.apple.com/guide/voice-memos/record-vmaa4b813415/mac)).